# C# calling a public non-static method using reflection without instantiating its class

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamicmethod

Is-it possible in C# to call a method (non-static) without instantiating its class e.g :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("method called");
    }
}
```

I've tried this method using the System.Reflection.Emit namespace, I copied the IL of MyMethod() to a dynamic method but got an exception :

> FatalExecutionEngineError was detected : 
>   The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x5dceccf5, on thread 0x2650. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

```
        Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Type t = a.GetType("Tutorial.MyClass");
        MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("MyMethod");
        MethodBody mb = m.GetMethodBody();

        DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("MethodAlias", null, Type.EmptyTypes, typeof(Tutorial.MainWindow), true);
        DynamicILInfo ilInfo = dm.GetDynamicILInfo();
        SignatureHelper sig = SignatureHelper.GetLocalVarSigHelper();
        ilInfo.SetLocalSignature(sig.GetSignature());
        ilInfo.SetCode(mb.GetILAsByteArray(), mb.MaxStackSize);

        try
        {
            dm.Invoke(this, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: `public static void MyMethod()` that's not non-static. and *NO* you cannot call a non-static method without creating an instance.

Comment: Did you mean to make `MyMethod` static?

Comment: Just out of curiousity - what are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Bala I've removed the static keyword, my mistake :(

Comment: @Ars What exactly are you trying to do, because, calling instance method without an instance doesn't make much sense. Maybe people on stackoverflow would be able to suggest a different path than what you have taken if you explain the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Bala Even with the Emit classes (DynamicMethod, ...).

Comment: It's just a challenge, I've heard about the System.Reflection.Emit namespace, and I tried to get the IL of MyMethod() and copy it to a DynamicMethod.

Comment: The exception I got on my 2nd code is : The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x5dceccf5, on thread 0x2650. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of.  Because it's not static.

I would just say "No" but my reply wasn't long enough for SO.